# How to Handle Denied Permissions Android M (EasyPermissions)

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

I'm using EasyPermissions to check if certain permissions have been granted in my android and and requesting them if not. Cool library, works great but I've still not gotten to figuring out how to handle if some permissions where denied.

so basically you run a code like this on create to check

```
if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(Splash.this, perms )) {

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        String SimSimSerial = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();

        Toast.makeText(Splash.this, "IMEI: " + IMEI + " SimSerial: " + SimSimSerial, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else {

        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(Splash.this, "Without these permissions, the app is unable to successfully complete authentication. Please allow us to access your device so that we can better serve you. "  ,PERMS_REQUEST_CODE, perms );
    }
```

code breakdown: if permissions exist, continue else request which is fine. My question is what if during request someone click on the never ask button. The guys at EasyPermissions have a function for that its

```
EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(Splash.this, permsList)
```

My dilemma is where to call this function as the request permissions method doesnt returns nothing (void). I tried something like

```
if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(Splash.this, perms )) {...
 } else if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(Splash.this, permsList)) {

 } else {
    EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(Splash.this, "Without these permissions, the app is unable to successfully complete authentication. Please allow us to access your device so that we can better serve you. "  ,PERMS_REQUEST_CODE, perms );
 }
```

but it always run the permissions denied one on start and not when a user actually click the never button in runtime. Any help is appreciated thanks..

link to EasyPermissions https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

Comment: Did you try to implement EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks in your Fragment/Activity in which you are using the Easy Permissions ?

Comment: No pls how do I invoke that? Was of the opinion that it was optional...

Comment: Yes implement EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks and then it will ask you to add methods and then you can handle your denial there

Comment: That makes sense, i'll give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pub/devrel/easypermissions/sample/MainFragment.java).

Here you have to implement the **EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks** with this you will be provided to add methods which will be **onRequestPermissionsResult**, **onPermissionsGranted**, **onPermissionsDenied**. Then in onPermissionsDenied you can handle your Denial status.
Try it and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank chief, this helped me understand a whole lot more.

Comment: Actually, `onRequestPermissionsResult` is not defined by `EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks`. That's a method inherited from `Activity` (or the support `Fragment` class).

Answer (score 12):

**Complete explanation for every case of permission if you don't want to use Easy Permissions**

```
/**
 *    Case 1: User doesn't have permission
 *    Case 2: User has permission
 *
 *    Case 3: User has never seen the permission Dialog
 *    Case 4: User has denied permission once but he din't clicked on "Never Show again" check box
 *    Case 5: User denied the permission and also clicked on the "Never Show again" check box.
 *    Case 6: User has allowed the permission
 *
 */
public void handlePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // This is Case 1. Now we need to check further if permission was shown before or not

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // This is Case 4.
        } else {
            // This is Case 3. Request for permission here
        }

    } else {
        // This is Case 2. You have permission now you can do anything related to it
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // This is Case 2 (Permission is now granted)
    } else {
        // This is Case 1 again as Permission is not granted by user

        //Now further we check if used denied permanently or not
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // case 4 User has denied permission but not permanently

        } else {
            // case 5. Permission denied permanently.
            // You can open Permission setting's page from here now.
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: good explanation, if we want to add alert dialog before showing permission dialog. e.g If user don't have permission and click on button for camera access then show a dialog just for information then user click on "OK" then permission dialog will show.  Can you please help me for this Thank you

Comment: @Navjot.jassal Watch case 4 please there you can show dialog and when user agree for the dialog info you can ask for permission

Comment: can you please do this change in code it would be helpful. I appreciate for this Thank you

Comment: Solved, Thank you